# TCL Alter or Remove an exact character combination from a string

Tags: tcl

On deletion of a file, I am trying to rename all files by the increment number of a variable.

I have a list of files. Each are named in hexadecimal and incremented based on how many files in the folder; when a new file is created in that folder.

> 312d416e64207768657265206172652077652e2e20f09f8e88 ;# 1-filename - 1st file 
>   332df09f8eb220556e64657220436f6e737472756374696f6e20f09f8eb2 ;# 2-filename 2nd file
>   332df09f8cb22043686e6167654c6f6720f09f8cb2 ;# 3-filename 3rd file

I am trying to remove the first four or the combination of: 3x2d from each of these files and then rename them with the correct sequence

My code is as follows:

```
set symbol [ixc::2Hex "-"] ;# 2d
set contents [glob -directory $dir *]
append sorted [lsort -dictionary $contents]

foreach item $sorted {
incr baseCount
set ze [file tail $item]

set hexCount [ixc::2Hex "$baseCount"] ;#convert ascii to hex
set hexZe "[string trim $ze "$hexCount$symbol"]" ;#trim the hexcount and delmiter from the file name
#set hexZe [regsub "$hexCount$symbol" $ze ""] ;#Alternative way of removing characters but buggy

puts "rename >> $item to $hexCount$symbol$hexZe" 
puts "----"

# catch the error if the "cannot rename same file" 
# this occurs when the file deletes 
# then rename tries to rename the same file as the same file

if { [catch {file rename $item $dir/$hexCount$symbol$hexZe} error] } {
continue
} else {
set fexist "$item"

#rename the file as the hexValue based off the counted ascii value 
#include the symbol and file name
#if the file does not exist such as the deleted file then skip

if { $fexist eq 1} { 
file rename $item $dir/$hexCount$symbol$hexZe   
} else { 
continue
}
```

This works as exactly as it does and is exactly the result I want

However it proceeds to trim any number of "2"

> 332df09f8eb220556e64657220436f6e737472756374696f6e20f09f8eb**2**

This resulting in broken hex if you were to decode it back in to ascii.

Using regsub. 
It works but provides funky results.

```
set hexZe [regsub "$hexCount$symbol" $ze ""]
```

resulting in something like:

> **372d382d**f09f8cb22043686e6167654c6f6720f09f8cb2 ;# result: 7-8-filename

I assumes it's because I'm removing the string "3x2d" from the string each time of cycle of the loop.

tl;dr: want to remove "312d" from the file name, and then rename the file with the correct incremented number based on the count of the directory seperated by a "-"

cheers

Answer (score 0):

The `string trim` command treats its second argument as a *set* of characters to remove, and it keeps on removing them from *both* ends of the string until none are left. To just remove from the left end of the string, there is `string trimleft`, but in this case you are better off using either:

```
# Save a copy of the string to remove in a variable for convenience
set pattern $hexCount$symbol

# How to do an exact prefix match
if {[string equal -length [string length $pattern] $pattern $ze]} {
    set hexZe [string range $ze [string length $pattern] end]
} else {
    # If it didn't match, fall back
    set hexZe $ze
}
```

or:

```
# NOTICE THE ANCHOR! Only want to do this *at the start of the string*
set hexZe [regsub "^$hexCount$symbol" $ze ""]
```

Be *very* careful with constructing regular expressions. While you're fine with hex characters, it's easy to get in a pickle if you have RE metacharacters in your pattern components.

---

For clarity, it's probably best to create a helper procedure.

```
proc RemovePrefix {string prefix} {
    set length [string length  $prefix]
    if {[string equal  -length $length  $prefix $string]} {
        return [string range  $string  $length end]
    }
    return $prefix
}

set hexZe [RemovePrefix $ze $hexCount$symbol]
```

Comment: Thanks, however, it's working in reverse to how I want it. Using the RemovePrefix proc, I get output like: **rename from 332df09f8eb220556e64657220436f6e737472756374696f6e20f09f8eb2 to 322d** when I am looking to remove 322d leaving **09f8eb220556e64657220436f6e737472756374696f6e20f09f8eb2**